Ideas to obtain projection matrix Amn(K) from QE
in a nutshell, I want to have access to the projection matrix that QE uses to calculate the orbital contributions/weights for each n and k (with &PROJWFC). Knowing that $w_{n,\mathbf{k},\alpha} = |A^\mathbf{k}_{mn}|^2$, in principle $A^\mathbf{k}_{mn}$ should be computed at some point. I am interested in the phase of the projection so sadly the weights in this case are not enough. Have any of you encountered this problem before? Any suggestions?
Thank you for your time!
M

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but pw2wannier90.x can calculate the Amn matrices  (.amn files) for the projection functions specified in the .win input. I'm not sure whether these are the same projection functions used by projwfc.x. You can find guides on how to use them in the wannier90 user guide available here.
